# Browser back button gives 'confirm form resubmission' in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, sitecore-mvc

When I click the back button in my browser while on my `xyz` page, I receive an error message which says *"Confirm Form Resubmission?*". Upon inspection of the browser, click the back button works properly, and any other interactions with my `xyz` page work such as clicking or scrolling. The issue arises when the page does not load, and no other actions on the page work.

Here is some of the code I am using:

```
$(function () {

    if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
        window.history.pushState('', null);
        $(window).on('popstate', function () {
            var store_code = getUrlParameter('search');
            var zipcode = getUrlParameter('zipcode');

            if (store_code != '' && zipcode != '') {
                window.location.href = "/locator?search=" + zipcode;
            }
        });
    }});
```

Comment: That's usually caused by navigating back to a page that had been originally loaded by form submission. For example, a login completion or search results.

Comment: The above code works fine in firefox. Chrome and edge cannot be customized back page gone